# Maven compiler plugin cannot resolve maven dependencies with version specified in included bill of material (bom)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

We currently have this bill of material (bom) configured for all our projects (libraries and microservices)

```xml
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
 ...
```

And we have a parent pom in which we define common behavior for all our microservices in which we include this bom.

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>nl.bro</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.bro-bill-off-material</artifactId>
                <version>${bro-bill-off-material.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            ...
```

And somewhat further in the file we define the build.plugins.plugin

```xml
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Note the versions are missing because we defined the versions in the bom. I would expect that maven would pick this up when we let a microservice project derive from this parent.

However this does not seem to work. We get an error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project jakarta.common-shared: Resolution of annotationProcessorPath dependencies failed: version can neither be null,
 empty nor blank -> [Help 1]
```

This strikes me as odd. Why would I have to redefine the version of MapStruct, Lombok or Hibernate modelgen? Isn't it the essence of a bill of material to have centralized version control of your dependencies?

Comment: I guess that the compiler plugin probably does not implement the full dependency resolution mechanism that is used for `<dependencies>`.

Comment: That's as far as I came.. But is that an omission or deliberate? Needing to redefine a version is not convenient (to say the least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`annotationProcessorPaths` will resolve versions from `dependencyManagement` starting with version 3.12.0

[MCOMPILER-391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-391)

Today version 3.12.0 is not released yet.
I will let you know when will be ready.

Comment: That's great to hear.. Is that also taking in account the included bom?